# Android ReCaptcha: Does instanciating a (synchronous!) Executor object in my Activity could cause its thread (and UI) to crash?

Tags: java, android, recaptcha

## Context

I use **Android SafetyNet ReCaptcha** to show the Google captcha in my Android app.

My app's users can sign-up, sign-in, sign-out. When a user starts my app, a splash screen appears. If the user isn't connected, he is invited to touch a button...:

- If he touches the button, the ReCaptcha is started. **a)** If the ReCaptcha is successfully completed, then the user can sign-up and sign-in with his Google account (I use Google Firebase Auth and even AuthUI). **b)** Otherwise, nothing occurs : he'll have to re-try to complete ReCaptcha.

### How I've implemented ReCaptcha

In résumé: I attach the `onClick` listener to the button. If the latter is clicked, thus, I call `verifyWithRecaptcha` in a (synchrone! and it's voluntary) `Executor`. Then I call the Google's servers to be sure the captcha has been completed by a humain being, not by a bot, thanks to my class `NetworkUseRecaptcha` which provides the result of the Google's servers.

#### My question

Since I use an `Executor` with a `AppCompatActivity` (named `SplashScreen`), in not asynchronous mode but actually synchronous (***so in the same thread than the activity and its UI***), is there any risk to throw an `Exception` (memory leaks, or something other)?

#### Resources

**I've followed this documentation:** https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha#send-request but I didn't find any useful information about my problem.

**I've not found any Stackoverflow question** about my problem.

#### SplashScreen.java (an AppCompatActivity class): The "onClick" event handler listeni

NB: `final Context that = this` is the current `AppCompatActivity` `SplashScreen` object.

```
final Context that = this;
button_splash_screen_recaptcha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final Executor executor = new Executor() {
            @Override
            public void execute(@NonNull Runnable command) {
                command.run();
            }
        };

        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SafetyNet.getClient(that).verifyWithRecaptcha("PUBLIC KEY")
                        .addOnSuccessListener(executor,
                                new OnSuccessListener<SafetyNetApi.RecaptchaTokenResponse>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(final SafetyNetApi.RecaptchaTokenResponse response) {
                                        String userResponseToken = response.getTokenResult();
                                        if (!userResponseToken.isEmpty()) {
                                            String[] parameters = new String[2];
                                            parameters[0] = "SECRET KEY";
                                            parameters[1] = userResponseToken;
                                            new NetworkUseRecaptcha(new RecaptchaPostExecuteCallback() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onTaskCompleted(String result, boolean background_error) {
                                                    if(background_error) {
                                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                            public void run() {
                                                                Toast.makeText(that,"Error N°2: Unable to check the captcha.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                        return;
                                                    }

                                                    try {
                                                        final JSONObject json_response = new JSONObject(result);
                                                        if(!json_response.isNull("success") && json_response.getBoolean("success")) {
                                                            final List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = ImmutableList.of(
                                                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
                                                            );
                                                            startActivityForResult(
                                                                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                                                                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                                                            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                                                                            .setAlwaysShowSignInMethodScreen(true)
                                                                            .setLogo(R.drawable.yellow_logo)
                                                                            .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
                                                                            .build(),
                                                                    REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN
                                                            );

                                                        } else {
                                                            Toast.makeText(that,"Error N°4: Unable to check the captcha.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        }
                                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                            public void run() {
                                                                Toast.makeText(that,"Error N°3: Unable to check the captcha.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }).execute(parameters);
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                        .addOnFailureListener(executor, new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                System.err.println(e);
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText(that,"Error N°1: Unable to check the captcha.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

#### NetworkUseRecaptcha.java: My class that allows me to contact the Google's servers to verify the captcha

```
class NetworkUseRecaptcha extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private final RecaptchaPostExecuteCallback post_execute_callback;
    private boolean background_error;

    NetworkUseRecaptcha(RecaptchaPostExecuteCallback post_execute_callback) {
        this.post_execute_callback = post_execute_callback;
        background_error = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[] parameters) {
        StringBuilder string_builder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
            HttpsURLConnection https_url_connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            https_url_connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            https_url_connection.setDoOutput(false);
            https_url_connection.setUseCaches(false);

            OutputStream os = https_url_connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            writer.write("secret=" + parameters[0] + "&response=" + parameters[1]);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            InputStream input_stream = https_url_connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader buffered_reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input_stream));
            String line;
            while((line = buffered_reader.readLine()) != null) {
                string_builder.append(line);
            }
            buffered_reader.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            background_error = true;
        }

        return string_builder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        post_execute_callback.onTaskCompleted(result, background_error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no risk of exception while invoking reCaptcha from main thread.

The reason is that although you have made call to reCaptcha API from main thread synchronously, it's safe because the `SafetyNet` API itself works asynchronously and spawn it's own worker threads to avoid `NetworkOnMainThread` Exception and deliver it's result back on `MainThread`.

Comment: Have you found something not well written? For example, is it a "good" practice to instanciate an `Executor` in my `AppCompatActivity` main thread (and, more precisely, a synchronous `Executor` )? In the documentation they indeed require an `Executor` but don't tell how to instanciate it.

Comment: you can altogether avoid using Executor in this case, you can even directly invoke reCaptcha API from button click listener.

Comment: Indeed, I've just deleted all references to the `Executor` object (in the callbacks definition, etc.). thanks!